# How do I add a php if condition to this wordpress code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a modified code to pull the wordpress custom post fields, because I want to be able to use a shortcode to display a form inside the custom post fields. So the following code works well. Now, I just need to figure out how I can display something else if that custom post field is empty...

This is my code that displays my custom post field info:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'form', true)); ?>
```

And if it's empty I want to display something else... (my custom post field key is called 'form')
How do I do that?

I tried to search for it but my code looks a bit different since I need to be able to add shortcodes to the custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just use and if/else statement.

```
 <?php 
   $result = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'form', true)); 

   if(empty($result)) {
     echo 'something else';
   } else {
     echo $result;
   }
 ?>
```